# Hiding toolbar in embed tag not work after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to hide toolbar that shows over pdf document in embed tag.It is working at first time but not working after postback.I also want that user should not be able to copy text from pdf.It is needed at any cost.Could someone please tell if there are alternate ways to do so ?

In code behind I used literal to add text dynamically:

```
string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"855px\" style='padding-left:20px;' height=\"700px\">";
embed += "</object>";
ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/admin/ShowPdf.ashx?Id=1&FilePath="), strFilePath);
```

In html:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also want that user should not be able to copy text from pdf.It is
>   needed at any cost

You can't, once you have served the content to client, you no longer have control over it. Client can print it, take screenshot, disable javascirpt (if you have added any additional checks to disable the copy) and get the content or can directly download the pdf if anyone wants.

Only thing you can do is you can make it tough for users to get the the content by

- Adding some JavaScript checks like disabling some of the keys.
- Converting the PDF to image/canvas or video, so that it become toguh
  for him to copy.